# Customize Analytics Report in Sharepoint-Online (Office 365)

Tags: central-administration, sharepoint-online, web-analytics, office-365

When I go to my site's analytics page, (www.mydomain.com/sites/mysite/_layouts/WebAnalytics/Report.aspx), I am able to see analytics data. For some reason, I have to go there instead of /_layouts/usagedetails.aspx. When I go to the latter site, it says that Usage logging is disabled, but again, when I go to the former, I see data.

Anyway, when I see the data, I am able to export to a spreadsheet just fine. I can get all the information in a .csv file. However, when I try to customize the report, I get an empty report that has 0's for all the dates regardless of what should be there.

I have read from other posts that you need to go into Central Administration and turn on the Claims To Windows Token Services (c2wts), but the catch is that I'm using Sharepoint Online and don't have a Central Administration. I am not one of the server admins, so I'm not sure what features are all available in Sharepoint Online Administration Center, but from what I've read it's not in there either.

Is there any way I can get the custom reports of this analytical data from Sharepoint-Online?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get barebones analytics with `.../_layouts/usage.aspx`